# contenteditable=false inside contenteditable=true block is still editable in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, contenteditable

I have the following HTML intending to make sure that the inner `span` isn't editable. This works in other browsers but not IE8.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  Luke, I am your father.
  <span contenteditable="false">I'm your son?! Ewww!</span>
  Don't speak back to me!
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate the point (use IE8 to test it): http://jsfiddle.net/haxhia/uUKPA/3/ .

How do I make sure that IE8 treats this properly as well?

Comment: i just tried it in FF 6 for OSX and i can edit everything...

Comment: @Dan, yeah anything but IE8 deals with this reasonably well.

Comment: @Gezim Do you have any idea if this was fixed in IE 9/10/11?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield, for some reason I thought it was fixed in IE9 but testing the JSFiddle here, it seems like it's not fixed in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/haxhia/uUKPA/3/

Comment: Still the same issue in IE11.

Comment: IE9 had this fixed, I thought. That's crazy!

Comment: It doesn't happen in Edge.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Okay, I already have discovered the answer much like how [Penicillin was discovered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Fleming#Accidental_discovery).

You see, playing around with this code, I mistakenly set `contenteditable` to `true` for the `span` and voila! It worked!

So, to make a `span` NON-contenteditable inside a contenteditable div, you just set its `contenteditable` attribute to `true`!

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  Luke, I am your father.
  <span contenteditable="true">I'm your son?! Ewww!</span>
  Don't speak back to me!
</div>
```

Here's the file to demonstrate (use IE8 to open it): https://codepen.io/hgezim/pen/qMppLg .

Lastly, I didn't post the question to get votes (although, they wouldn't hurt!), but since the solution was so ridiculous and I didn't find it here, I thought someone may find this tip time saving.

Comment: Sorry, have to down-vote this because that is the kind of behavior that will be interpreted as a bug and eventually (even if it will takes years) be changed so the second element is still editable.

Comment: @John, meanwhile people have to fix this issue, today. Do you actually think Microsoft will fix this in IE8?!

Comment: @user1868084, I just uploaded the solution as a file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yc3rrtkji3rupr/contenteditableIE8.html download it and use IE8 to see the solution.

Comment: Upvoted, because this is exactly how Microsoft implements their contenteditable div in Outlook Web Access's "To Addresses" field. In IE, inner span (that we do not want editable) set to true, in Chrome, it is set to false. Both work, IE's doesn't make sense.

Comment: As pointed out by Alexvx, this solution is not airtight. The user can still edit the inner element after double-clicking it.

Comment: @Sully, as @Alexvx noted in another answer `the problem with contenteditable="true" inside contenteditable="true" (to make it not editable) on IE is that double clicking on the inner element makes it editable`. Actually it makes them resizable as well. Do you know how Microsoft resolves that in Outlook Web Access's "To Addresses" field?

Comment: @jayarjo @Sully Adding `pointer-events: none;` to the inner HTML element's css and adding             `ondragstart = e => e.preventDefault()` to the content editable parent seems to solve the issue of allowing users to double click as well as resize/drag the inner HTML.

Answer (score 18):

The problem with contenteditable="true" inside contenteditable="true" (to make it not editable) on IE is that double clicking on the inner element makes it editable

Solution

```
Grandparent tag as contenteditable true

Parent tag as contenteditable false

Child tag as contenteditable false
```

the contents of child tag will not be editable for sure

```
    <ul contenteditable="true">
        <li>By default, this content is editable via its 
        inherited parent elements value.</li>

    <li contenteditable="false" ><span contenteditable="false">This content is     
    <b>not</b> 
    editable for sure</span></li>
    </ul>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uUKPA/35/)

Comment: Even this solution is not airtight. Carefully navigating with the arrow keys, you can bring the caret into the non-editable element, and edit at will. To reproduce, go to the fiddle, click on the second line, then press down key. This brings your caret into the third line that was supposed to be impenetrable. Tested in IE11; trying not to bother with older versions anymore.

Comment: What if you simply disable doubleclick on inner cE elements?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same problem today and after trying for a while figured a solution that works for me on IE. Add a click event listener to the child contenteditable element. In the event handler do as below

```js
 document.querySelector('.simulated-icon').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    evt.stopPropogation;
    evt.preventDefault;
    return false;
 });
```

```html
<div class="simulated-icon"><span>Icon text</span></div>
```

As you can see here returning false on the click event listener for the child content editable tells IE to not allow the edit. This works if there is a click event on the parent node and we check if the target child node is clicked in the event listener. Good luck.