# looking for specific WYSIWYG editor functionality. Recommendations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, wysiwyg

I'm developing an application that requires very specific WYSIWYG functionality. I need a way to generate HTML consistently and around elements that my application generates. The container used must be a DIV element, there must be a way to block/strip formatting when pasting, and the tags used in the HTML must be consistent between browsers. Also, it is important to have hooks for the backspace key, so that any special elements that I insert into the DIV from my application can be handled appropriately. Anyone have any suggestions? Maybe a good starting point?

Comment: I would try CKeditor. I'm not sure if it can/can't do everything you need it to, but it's the best WYSIWYG editor I know of. It's highly customizable and free, so you might as well give it a shot: www.ckeditor.com

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "around elements your application generates"? Should this run in a browser? If so, have you looked at TinyMCE?

Comment: This actually sounds like a pretty basic set of requirements that most (if not all) WYSIWYG editors can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)?

Comment: I have, actually. There is one important bit missing. It doesn't look like the noneditable plugin supports this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522848/contenteditable-false-inside-contenteditable-true-block-is-still-editable-in-ie8). I actually need to make certain elements inside the contenteditable container to be uneditable and unremovable

Comment: I believe you can do that, but you will need to add additional code within your tiny MCE instance to account for this.  It isn't offered as a feature within the editor.