# contenteditable nested browser differences

Tags: contenteditable

From what I read, there are quite a few browser differences in how contenteditable elements are handled. (i.e. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522848/contenteditable-false-inside-contenteditable-true-block-is-still-editable-in-ie8)). When a 'contenteditable=true' element contains a 'contenteditable=false' element, the 'contenteditable=false' element can still be removed with a backspace. Firefox won't let you do that, but it is considered a bug [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685445). Is there a cross-browser way to keep elements in a contenteditable container from ever being removed or modified?

Comment: This may be resolved now, at least in Chrome. Check this one: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238000

Answer (score 0):

May be [Medium.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/) will be helpful, but that depends on what's your purpose of using contenteditable. At least they say "Medium.js is html5 compliant and has been tested in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, & IE8+. Browser support is constantly improving!" They have some demos with "widgets" (that's how they call insets with `contenteditable="false"`) on the main page.