# Contenteditable tag continuation

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Small intro to what's happening before the question:

When typing text in a contenteditable that contains html tags, it continues inserting within the tag if you are to the right of the tag. For instance, if I have text like this:

```
The <b>quick</b> fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

and it renders like this

The **quick**| fox jumped over the lazy dog.

My cursor is located at the pipe position, directly after the word *quick*. If I enter in *brown* I will get

```
The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

The **quick brown**| fox jumped over the lazy dog.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mBzvs/

My question is, how do I remove this tag-continuation feature for other tags such as span? I'd like to keep it for the `<b>` tag but I don't want this to happen for the `<span>` tag.

Comment: An example on something like jsbin.com would help.

Comment: Added example as suggested

Comment: It's curious, I don't have this problem on Firefox 28... When I put my cursor next to `quick` and write something, it's not in the `<b>` tag...

Comment: It happens 100% of the time on Chrome. But I just tested it on Firefox 26 as well. If you move the cursor using the arrow keys it will take the tag of the previous position it was in. So if you moved from right to left, it will be unbolded. If you moved from left to right, it will be bolded. If you click directly at the position, it will also be bolded.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see any tag continuation issues in your jsfiddle link either, what are your settings, browser version?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 32.0.1700.41
When I click on the div in the "result" box and add brown after quick, it is bolded.

Comment: I think the logic here will do it, but it's a mess trying to move the caret in a contenteditable element. http://jsfiddle.net/PeuuC/2/

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and other WebKit browsers will always place the caret at the end of the `<b>` element rather than the start of the next text node. See [this WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23189), for example. Also [this one](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15256). Firefox gives you more control.

None of the workaround options are good. See the linked WebKit bugs for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Until some found a better solution I would suggest you set `contenteditable="false"` to `<b>` tag.

```
The <b contenteditable="false">quick</b> fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Since:

1. You probably want the content in `<b>` tag not editable. If not, it's very hard to tell what people wants when he starts typing next to the last character in that tag.
2. It's easy to fulfill your second requirement:
   *I'd like to keep it for the b tag but I don't want this to happen for the span tag.*

Note: You need additional code for IE. See [contenteditable=false inside contenteditable=true block is still editable in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522848/contenteditable-false-inside-contenteditable-true-block-is-still-editable-in-ie8)