# ContentEditable element and Character IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am going to assume this is a bug in IE 11. But it looks like when I have a `contenteditable='false'` inside a `contenteditable=true` the folloing charater or space becomes part of the "span"

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="hello">
Hello world!<span contenteditable='false'>Number 42</span>Good Bye world!    
</p>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAgDr/4/). As you can see when you move the cursor from left to right the cursor jump from Number to after G as if `<span contenteditable='false'>Number 42</span>Good` is encase in `<span contenteditable='false'>Number 42G</span>ood`. Does anybody know of a work around for this?

Comment: [Possibly the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7522910/2782261). Setting the inner-span to `true` instead of `false` will make the content not editable.

Comment: @AaronGotreaux I guess I should mention that already some of the other post here on stack overflow. But my main concern here is that the `G` from Good Bye is now part of `Number 42`