# HTML5 - contenteditable="false" nested in contenteditable="true"

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm having very different behaviors with nested contenteditable="false" elements within a parent contenteditable="true:

```
  <pre>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    <span>I'm supposed to be editable</span>
    <p contenteditable="false">I'm NOT supposed to be editable.<br>Neither should I.</p>
    <span contenteditable="false">I'm NOT supposed to be editable.</span>
  </div>
  </pre>
```

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5z44zhu/) exemplifies how two elements that should not be editable are in fact editable with Internet Explorer 11 but not Google Chrome. What gives?

I have seen some people applying a strange workaround by setting them to "true", which indeed works for IE, but has the opposite effect on Google Chrome (as it should).

The answer for this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522848/contenteditable-false-inside-contenteditable-true-block-is-still-editable-in-ie8) is dated from 2013. Three years after, is this still the current scenario ?

Edit:
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhgkvjj5/) almost achieves the wanted result. However, if you set the cursor to "Don't move.." and move it to the left until you reach the non-editable span, you will gain focus and able to edit it. Any ideas to avoid this behavior ?

Affected browser: Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Internet Explorer 11. Section [7.6.1 of the HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) states:

> The `contenteditable` attribute is an enumerated attribute whose keywords are the empty string, `true`, and `false`. The empty string and the `true` keyword map to the *true* state. The `false` keyword maps to the *false* state. In addition, there is a third state, the *inherit state*, which is the *missing* value default (and the *invalid* value default).
>
> **The *true* state indicates that the element is editable. The *inherit* state indicates that the element is editable if its parent is. The *false* state indicates that the element is not editable.**

This means that a `contenteditable=false` element within a `contenteditable=true` element should not be editable.

Furthermore, a `contenteditable=true` element within a `contenteditable=true` element should have its content editable. Meaning the answer to the question you linked is actually invalid (although when it was posted this may have been the case).

Comment: that feel when this is still relevant in 2019