# Make substring uneditable within larger div string, while also preserving the unique substring CSS (distinct from rest of text styling in div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Setup:**
Below is a tweet example appearing as an editable  text:
"First words of tweet, @tweetaddress last words of tweet"

**Requirement and Problem:**
I'd like the user to be able to edit the text, but NOT change the @tweetaddress,  which I have working. However, I also would like the @tweetAddress to be color:blue while the rest of the text is color:white.  I can achieve this result initially through the use of a span wrapped around the @tweetaddress. (shown is code below.)

I'm fine on JavaScript detecting if the @tweetaddress has changed.  BUT...

The problem:
...if the user starts typing right next to the @tweetaddress, the styling from the 'never-change' class applies to all the new text.  Is there a way to limit my  to only include the @tweetaddress, so that all new text into the div is outside it and not blue?

I've tried initially putting different spans on either side of the @tweetaddress 'never-change' span, but if the user deletes the characters in the other spans and then retypes, the new letters still come out blue.

I'd really love to hear any ideas on how I could proceed.

HTML

```
<div contenteditable id="text-input" placeholder="Tweet text here">First words of tweet,<span class="never-change">@tweetaddress</span> last words of tweet</div>
```

CSS:

```
.never-change{
    color:blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#text-input').keydown(function() {
    textStart = $(this).html();
    tweetAddress = '@tweetaddress';
} 
$('#text-input').keyup(function() {
    textEnd = $(this).text();
    if (textEnd.indexOf(placeholderText) > -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Twiiter name. Cannot edit");
    $(this).html(textStart);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate, definitely related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522848/contenteditable-false-inside-contenteditable-true-block-is-still-editable-in-ie8

Comment: I read the link and applied the contenteditable="false" to my 'never-change' span.  Worked great.  All new text on either side is white and the link remains blue.  Thank you so much for sending this link.  Here is my final JS, which drops this HTML into the #text-input div.  So simple: $('#text-input').html('<span contenteditable=false class=never-change>' + tweetAddressPlaceholder + '</span>');  Thanks @Gerrit0